# Spring Data Slice in Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, pageable

Actually i'm using Slice to pagination in queries in Cassandra. My repository is declared like this:

```
@Repository
public interface MovementsRepository<T> extends CassandraRepository<Movements, MovementsPK> {

    @Query("SELECT movementNumber FROM KEYSPACE.MOVEMENTS)
    Slice<Movements> downOrder(@Param("agency") String agency, @Param("account") String account, @Param("initialDate") LocalDate initialDate, @Param("finalDate") LocalDate finalDate, Pageable pageable);

}
```

And I do the search in the first page this way:

```
Slice<Movements> slice = this.movementsRepository.downOrder(agency, account, initialDate, finalDate, CassandraPageRequest.first(1000));
```

To go for the next pages I can get the property slice.nextPageable() like this:

```
slice = this.movementsRepository.downOrder(agency, account, initialDate, finalDate, slice.nextPageable());
```

But I need to paginate every request, so I need to retrive in JSON the pagingState or whetever I can use to set nextPageable when the second, third... request comes to I know the next search is in next pages, it's possible to do this in the way I'm doing or other way?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Slice can only navigate to the next slice. Also Slice provides details whether there is more data to fetch. So you can run it in a while loop as follows:

```
while(slice.hasNext()){
 slice = this.movementsRepository.downOrder(agency, account, 
             initialDate, finalDate, slice.nextPageable());
}
```

Comment: I have a timeout limitation in my infra, which only allows a request stay for 20 seconds, I have clients with milions of registries, so I need to paginate in other request, is there a way to store the slice, or only the slice.nextPageable() and return it in a JSON, so I use this value to populate the Slice. It's exactly what I need, navigate through the next slice, one by one, to slice 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and consequently. The only particularity is that I can't do this in the same execution.